# iOS Programming Center Group of UIViews

Tags: ios, view, uiview, geometry, centering

I am wondering how/if I could do this: **center a group of UIView's  in a superview.** The end result would be a 'group' of views that are visibly centered in their superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is a 2 step process; first add the UIViews to an array and then do a fast enumeration to center them as a "group"

```
//step 1: create the objects
self.label1= [[UILabel alloc]init];
self.label1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
self.label1.text=@"1";

self.label2= [[UILabel alloc]init];
self.label2.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
self.label2.text=@"2";

self.label3= [[UILabel alloc]init];
self.label3.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
self.label3.text=@"3";


//step2: create the array and add the objects to the array
self.arrayOfViews=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:4];
[self.arrayOfViews addObject:self.label1];
[self.arrayOfViews addObject:self.label2];
[self.arrayOfViews addObject:self.label3];



//step3: use fast enumeration to be able to control them as "group"
for(UIView* currentViewObject in self.arrayOfViews)
{
    currentViewObject.alpha=0.3;
    currentViewObject.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-sizeOfObject/2,self.view.bounds.size.height/2-sizeOfObject/2,sizeOfObject,sizeOfObject);
    [self.view addSubview:currentViewObject];
}
```

Step 1 and the alpha setting is just for testing purpose here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What's the purpose of `initWithCapacity:4`?

Comment: You need to alloc init the NSMutableArray before using it. Mutable arrays expand as needed; 4 simply establishes the object’s initial capacity. If you would put 2, it would work as well.

Comment: Ok, so you *could* just  use `init`?

Comment: Since NSMutableArray class inherits from NSArray, it seems you can. I just have not seen it being used in NSMutableArray. It has always been -initWithCapacity.

Comment: Well, I always use just plain old `init`. Just wanted to see if there was something special about it.